# IEnumerable concepts - Get All and Get One

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I have a function that has IEnumerable and it will loop a list of record building a string. I would also like to use the same function when I return just one object. In the middle tier there is two functions one returns the list and other returns the  object.

Do I have to build a new function that will take in the object?

```
          public List<Model.Disease> GetDisease()
            {
             var Disease = (from Diseases in db.Diseases
                  select new Model.Disease
                  {
                  DiseaseId = Diseases.DiseaseId,
                  DiseaseName = Diseases.DiseaseName,
                      drug = (from d in db.Drug
                      where (Diseases.DiseaseId == d.DiseaseId
                      select new drug
                      {
                      DrugId = d.drug,
                      DrugName = d.drugName
                      }).OrderBy(m => m.DrugName).ToList(),
                   }).OrderBy(d => d.DiseaseName).ToList();
                  return Disease;
                 }
            }

            public List<Model.Disease> GetDiseaseById(Guid DiseaseId)
            {
                var Disease = (from Diseases in db.Diseases
                    select new Model.Disease
                    {
                    DiseaseId = Diseases.DiseaseId,
                    DiseaseName = Diseases.DiseaseName,
                        drug = (from d in db.Drug
                        where (Diseases.DiseaseId == d.DiseaseId && d.DrugId == 
 1)
                        select new drug
                            {
                            DrugId = d.drug,
                            DrugName = d.drugName
                            }).OrderBy(m => m.DrugName).ToList(),
                   }).OrderBy(d => d.DiseaseName).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
       return Disease;   
                }
            }


        private string BuildreimbursementDisplay(IEnumerable<ReimbursementDisease> displayList)
```

Comment: Can you write a meaningful title?

Comment: What you are describing is similar to the `Find()`, `First()`, and `Single()` IEnumerable extension methods, but all are different and all have their own use cases. what are you trying to accomplish. I think regardless, you are going to need a second method.

Comment: or alternatively hacky way, but would work : BuildreimbursementDisplay(new IEnumerabe<ReimbursementDisease>().Add(the_single_disease));

Comment: That is assuming that you already have functions that returns ienumerable of objects and single object. To get single object from list of objects - use Hogan's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the following just fine.

```
public Model.Disease GetFirstDisease()
{
  return GetDisease().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

something like this would also work

```
public Model.Disease GetDiseaseById(Guid DiseaseId)
{
  return GetDisease().Where(x => x.DiseaseId == DiseaseId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

If you are trying to just use one function to "be fancy" or make it "simpler", don't.  Reuse is important (like I did above) but making it very complicated for no good reason just makes code bad.  To get to fancy -- keep it simple and it will be easier to maintain and find bugs.

Comment: I updated the post with more information on the linq statement when I do the FirstOrDefault I get the error system.collections.generic.list.

Comment: @Jefferson -- of course you do -- it does not make sense to use `ToList()` here.  just take that out.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you already have 2 methods. One that gets list of diseases

> public List GetDisease()

and one that gets single disease by guid

> public Model.Disease GetDiseaseById(Guid DiseaseId)

Considering that you asked if you can reuse BuildreimbursementDisplay(IEnumerable displayList) for both single disease and list of diseases, and you're happy the way it works - yes, you can :

```
var disease = GetDiseaseById([disease_guid]);
string result = BuildreimbursementDisplay(new List<Model.Disease>().Add(disease));
```

That will essentially convert single disease to list with only one member. Not ideal, but I can assume that BuildreimbursementDisplay does something like this:

```
string BuildreimbursementDisplay(List<Model.Disease> diseases)
{
string foo ="";

foreach (var disease in diseases)
  {
  foo += <...>;
  }
return foo;
}
```

So it will loop only once.

Note : You would need to check against disease == null scenarios.

Comment: I updated the post with more information on the linq statement when I do the FirstOrDefault I get the error system.collections.generic.list.